# Understanding django grafana dashboard

Tags: django, prometheus, grafana, django-prometheus

I am trying out django dashboards for grafana. I imported a dashbord from grafana.com. One of the panels looks like below:
[image]

I am unable get the meaning of the information shown by the graph. Naively, I believe it is meant to show average request latency for the selected duration. But then what does it mean by 50th quantile here? Also what is meant by `by (le)` here?

Comment: `sum by (le)` means aggregating over same values of `le`.

Comment: [The 0.5-quantile is known as the median](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#quantiles). No clue why median is used here instead of average, though.